# How to prove $(A-B)∩C=(A∩C)-(B∩C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I thought a lot but I couldn't prove this. How can I prove it? $$(A-B)∩C=(A∩C)-(B∩C)$$

Comment: You can show mutual inclusion or you can unwind the def of $A \setminus B = A \cap \overline B$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{alignat}{1}
(A\cap C)\setminus (B\cap C) &= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge x\in C \wedge \neg(x\in B\wedge x\in C)\} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge (x\in C \wedge (x\notin B\vee x\notin C))\} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge ((x\in C \wedge x\notin B)\vee (x\in C\wedge x\notin C))\} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge (x\in C \wedge x\notin B)\} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge x\in C \wedge x\notin B\} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A \wedge \neg(x\in B)\wedge x\in C\} \\
&= (A\setminus B)\cap C \\
\end{alignat}

Answer (score 0):

Use $X\setminus(Y\cap Z)=(X\setminus Y)\cup(X\setminus Z)$ $$(A\cap C)\setminus (B\cap C)=((A\cap C)\setminus B)\cup ((A\cap C)\setminus C)=((A\cap C)\setminus B)\cup\emptyset$$

Comment: this wasn't really helpful

Comment: I ain't no Taylor and I ain't no tailor. ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯